# Reading gz file with php

Tags: php, gzip, simplexml

I am writing a script in php4 that downloads a xml file that has been compressed into a .gz file. The normal file is 25MB, when compressed into a .gz file its only 2.5MB. My question is, is there any benefits of downloading the file in compressed .gz file other than the smaller file size? In order to process the xml file I still have to uncompress it locally on my server and then process this big 25MB xml file correct? I ask this because after uncompressing it then processing it just takes forever. Im also using simplexml that takes the xml file and converts it into an array. Any help/suggestions would be appreciated. Even if I just have the full 25MB xml file on my local server without having to decompress it, it still is very slow.

Comment: @John - wrong assumption, it take forever because u try to load a 25Mb file using simplexml, use a smaller xml for testing first

Comment: PHP4?  **PHP4**?  PHP **4**?  Really?  Why on earth would anybody write new code targeted for PHP4 in this day in age???  (And I don't buy the legacy code argument, since 4 is unsupported so it makes more sense to upgrade to 5 (it's not hard, really) than to continue using 4)...

Comment: Thank you for the response! I figured that was the case, yes I was using a smaller xml file for testing. Im now in the process of making it live, sorry I re-read my question and it wasnt clear on that. Do you have an alternative process rather than using simplexml? Or will I have this issue no matter what process I have if Im going to be processing a 25MB xml file?

Comment: ircmaxell, this isnt a debate about what version to use. This isnt a personal side project, Im not going to refuse to help someone because they still use php4. Would I prefer php5? Uhm yes, but it isnt as black and white as you make it to be. But I do appreciate the feedback, I agree I rather be doing this in php5.

Comment: @John - `simplexml` is for simple xml :-( it should able to handle most of things PS use `@username` at the beginning of the comment to notify the user u want to notify

Comment: @John - depend on the xml structure, u can consider split the big xml into few smaller xml file and store the parse results into separate files, and after done all the parsing, consolidate all the parse results again

Comment: @ajreal Thanks for the PS. Well the xml file is simple its just a lot of records. I will see about breaking it up, the feed is coming from a provider not something I have much control of. So I will talk to them, I just thought maybe I was missing something with the whole gzip thing other than it makes the file transfer smaller/faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're correct that you will still have to process the uncompressed file either way.  You might be able to run some tests against the .gz file, but definitely not parse its xml.

Answer (score 0):

The question was:

> is there any benefits of downloading the file in compressed .gz file other than the smaller file size?

The answer is: there's one obvious benefit; You will download less data, so the transfer will be faster. Just open the file with [`gzopen()`](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.gzopen.php) instead of `fopen()`. Of course, the processing part of the script will remain terribly slow.

I have no advice for a XML parser in PHP 4 as I am fortunate enough to have steered clear of XML in my PHP 4 days.